# why is I18n.locale not a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I am accessing the I18n.locale variable to determine the language and I have to convert it to a string to do comparisons all the time.

```
I18n.locale.to_s
```

As in

```
I18n.locale.to_s == "en" ? "h2-high-quality.gif" : "h2-high-quality-fr.gif"
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this the way it must be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`I18n.locale` is a symbol. You don't need to convert to string to do comparisons, rather just do a comparison against a symbol:

```
I18n.locale == :en ? "h2-high-quality.gif" : "h2-high-quality-fr.gif"
```